# About exact sequences of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I am currently trying to understand "Proprietes de descente des varietes a fibre cotangent ample" by M. Martin-Deschamps, and I can't understand the first corollary. That is : given a scheme $S$ of finite type over a field $k$ and an exact sequence of vector bundles :

$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_S \to E \to F \to 0$$

the corollary states that :

$$\mathbb{P}(E) - \mathbb{P}(F) \text{ is affine}$$

I've been trying to look at it from every angle, and I must be missing something very simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: The article says the morphism $P(E)-P(F)\to S$ (small typo in the article and she writes $X$ for $S$) is affine, not $P(E)-P(F)$ is affine.